# Trying to understand deck plans for pergola post

Tags: deck, pergola

The deck plans I want to use has a pergola on the deck. It appears to use the same 6x6 post for both the deck and the pergola as can be seen in the rendering included with the plans:

[image: Deck render]

I can't figure out how to make this work though. If you were to notch the 6x6 you'll have a much weaker post for the pergola above. Looking at the plans just confuses me more because it appears to notch the post for the rim joist as well. You'd be left with a pretty weak point for the pergola above (a 2x4 basically). [image]

Neither the provided front or side elevation diagrams clear things up either:

[image: Post front elevation] Front

[image: Post side elevation] Side

If the pergola and deck posts are actually supposed to be two separate 6x6 pieces what would be the best way to attach the pergola post to the deck?